# Netezza Equivalent to T-SQL ROWVERSION or PL/SQL ORA_ROWSCN

Tags: sql-server, oracle, change-data-capture, netezza

Is there a Netezza equivalent to the MSSQL ROWVERSION or the Oracle ORA_ROWSCN?  Essentially I'd like to know if a record changed and be confident that it changed.  Using a checksum isn't reliable 100% of the time.

Comment: Sorry for a lame question, but why checksum is not reliable? AFAIK, checksum will be the same only if new values are the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the `ROWVERSION` behaviour, but `ORA_ROWSCN` I believe would still change if you were to update a row with completely identical values. In other words, the row contents would remain the same but its SCN would be different.

The only practically reliable way to detect the actual change in column values would be to calculate the row checksum or hash.

To answer your question though, consider using the `createxid` special column in Netezza: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ntz/v7r0m3/topic/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_data_types_ntz_internal.html

And again, a changed `createxid` value would not necessarily mean that any column values have changed.